# Rails: How To Deal With Many Subsets of Data From One Model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Rails 3.0.3 application (stuck on a Dreamhost shared server).

I have a page that displays averages calculated from subsets of data from one model.

Right now, each average is calculated individually, like this:

From the view, I'm using the `current_user` helper provided by Devise authentication to call  the average methods that are located in the user model, like so:

```
<%= current_user.seven_day_weight_average %>
<%= current_user.fourteen_day_weight_average %>
<%= current_user.thirty_day_weight_average %>
```

Here's the public methods and the averaging method in the user model:

```
def seven_day_weight_average
 calculate_average_weight(7)
end

def fourteen_day_weight_average
 calculate_average_weight(14)
end

def thirty_day_weight_average
 calculate_average_weight(30)
end

. . .
private
def calculate_average_weight(number_days)
  temp_weight = 0
  weights_array = self.weights.find_all_by_entry_date(number_days.days.ago..Date.today)
  unless weights_array.count.zero?
    weights_array.each do |weight|
      temp_weight += weight.converted_weight
    end
    return (temp_weight/weights_array.count).round(1).to_s
  else
    return '0.0'
  end
end
```

This doesn't seem very efficient - the database is queried for every average calculated.

How can I calculate and make these averages available to the page with one database query?

Answer (score 2):

You could cache an array of converted weights for the last 30 days (presuming 30 is the maximum days back), something like this:

```
def calculate_average_weight(number_days)
  @converted_weights ||= weights.where("entry_date > ?", 30.days.ago).group_by(&:entry_date).sort_by do |date,weights|
    date
  end.collect do |date,weights|
    weights.collect(&:converted_weight)
  end
  weights_during_period = @converted_weights[0..number_days-1].flatten
  weights_during_period.sum / weights_during_period.length
end
```

Explanation:

Firstly, `||=` gets or sets `@converted_weights` (ie don't bother setting it unless it's nil or false). This ensures only one db hit. Next, we find all weights from 30 days ago and group by date. This returns an array of `[date, weights]`, which we sort by date. Then we collect the converted weights for each date, so we end up with: `[weights on day 1], [weights on day 2], ...`.

Now, the calculation: we store values spanning the number of days from the array in `weights_during_period`. We flatten the values and calculate the average value.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Not sure what I'm supposed to do with @converted_weights. I can see it contains the converted_weight values but it's returning nil to the calling XXX_day_weight_average call. My Ruby knowledge is very limited - is `@converted_weights[-number_days..-1].sum` supposed to return the average?

Comment: @jacoulter see above - I've simplified and corrected the code, and added some explanation.

Comment: thanks for taking the time to explain this. I got it working, but I'm still hitting the database every time the method is called (which is to be expected.) Is there a way to call for the range needed and then load instance variables that are available to the calling web page?

Comment: It will only cache the db hit when called from the same instance (in the same request cycle). Can you post the context where the method is being called from?

Comment: Please see my edits to my original post. I'm calling the methods from the view via the `current_user` helper provided by the Devise authentication gem. The controller is empty - I call the view with a GET.  Thanks!